# uninstall netbeans8.2 Atom Theme

Tags: netbeans-8

I've installed the Atom Fonts and Colors Theme for Netbeans but I want to uninstall it, I went to Tools->Options->Appearence but is not in the list,There is another way to unninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall the **Atom** theme from NetBeans:

- Select **Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors**
- Ensure that **Atom** is selected as the **Profile ->** click the **Delete** button.

[image: DeleteProfile]